# Parse Server not sending Push Notifications

Tags: ios, parse-server

I have created a simple iOS App and I want it to be able to send push notifications to my users.

I have instaled Parse Server and Parse Dashboard on my VPS and configured my index.js as follows:

```
var api = new ParseServer({
  databaseURI: databaseUri || 'mongodb://localhost:27017/dev',
  cloud: process.env.CLOUD_CODE_MAIN || __dirname + '/cloud/main.js',
  appId: process.env.APP_ID || 'herdeira',
  masterKey: process.env.MASTER_KEY || '*********', //Add your master key here. Keep it secret!
  serverURL: process.env.SERVER_URL || 'http://localhost:1337/parse',  // Don't forget to change to https if needed
  push: {
    ios: [
      {
        pfx: 'push-herdeira-dev.p12', // Dev PFX or P12
        bundleId: 'com.ceizs.herdeira',
        production: false // Dev
      },
    ]
  }
});
```

Everything looks fine, every time I install the App on an iPhone, the number of installation count rises, so it seems to me that my App can comunicate to the Parse server.

But when I try to send a Push Notification, the message I get is "Saved" and the message is never delivered.

I need some light.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in this case was that I was not using an absolute path to the .P12 file. So here is the solution:

```
push: {
    ios: [
      {
        pfx: '/absolute/path/to/file.p12', // Dev PFX or P12
        bundleId: 'com.company.app',
        production: true // false if dev mode
      },
    ]
  }
```

Comment: I am having the same issue and am not sure if my .p12 file has its absolute or relative path. It begins with: "/Users/filetopaths/etc/file.p12". Should I have something in front of /Users? or is that enough?